# how to get a value in Customized listview with button .. (android)

Tags: android, listview, button

I really need a help with this.. 
I have a listview with buttons within the list. 
What I want to do is to get the value of the current list where the button is pressed.. (id and name) 
I have a myClickHandler where when the button is pressed it will call this..

```
            public void myClickHandler(View v){
     ListView lvItems = getListView();
    String name = null ;
    for (int i=0; i<lvItems.getChildCount(); i++) 
        {
    }

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            AllProductsActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
        alertDialog.setMessage("You have selected "+ name);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
            });
```

And will display some alertDialog with the given details..

A big thanks in advance to anyone who will kindly help me with this..

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for info from the row of the button clicked you can do this:

```
public void myClickHandler(View v){ 
    LinearLayout ll = v.getParent();  // v is the button, the parent should be the rowlayout, assuming LinearLayout
    TextView tv = ll.findViewById(R.id.listviewtext);  // find your textview in the LinearLayout for the row
    String ListText = tv.getText().toString();  // Get the text form the TextView

    // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please watch the tutorial of listview:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

then, have an onClickListener for each of the views via the getView to be the same , and get the value from the viewHolder of them .
that's it.